# Camel kafka Component unable to read messages from topic with ssl enable

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, apache-camel

The camel Kafka component is unable to read the messages with ssl enable, and it's not giving any errors also, below one is my router

Anyone, please help me how to resolve this type of issue, it's not showing error/failure logs also.

```
from("kafka:testtopic9?brokers=<domain-name>:9092"
        + "&groupId=test"
        + "&sslKeyPassword=12345"
        + "&sslKeystorePassword=12345"
        + "&securityProtocol=SASL_SSL"
        + "&sslTruststoreLocation=kafka.client.truststore.jks"
        + "&saslMechanism=PLAIN"
        + "&keyDeserializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.IntegerDeserializer"
        + "&valueDeserializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer"
        + "&saslJaasConfig=org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username=\"user1\" password=\"user1")
    .log("fetching data from broker :: ${body}")
```

**In the logs it's showing only config properties values and it's not showing further logs like subscribing to the topic etc... :**

```
<pre>
03-12-2020 12:56:06.871 [main] INFO  o.s.s.c.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor.initialize - Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
03-12-2020 12:56:07.538 [main] INFO  o.a.c.i.c.DefaultTypeConverter.doStart - Type converters loaded (core: 195, classpath: 14)
03-12-2020 12:56:07.899 [main] INFO  o.a.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol.log - Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
03-12-2020 12:56:07.923 [main] INFO  o.s.b.w.e.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.start - Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
03-12-2020 12:56:07.942 [main] INFO  o.a.c.spring.boot.RoutesCollector.loadXmlRoutes - Loading additional Camel XML routes from: classpath:camel/*.xml
03-12-2020 12:56:07.942 [main] INFO  o.a.c.spring.boot.RoutesCollector.loadXmlRests - Loading additional Camel XML rests from: classpath:camel-rest/*.xml
03-12-2020 12:56:07.951 [main] INFO  o.a.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext.start - Apache Camel 2.25.2 (CamelContext: camel-1) is starting
03-12-2020 12:56:07.952 [main] INFO  o.a.c.m.ManagedManagementStrategy.doStart - JMX is enabled
03-12-2020 12:56:08.104 [main] INFO  o.a.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext.doStartCamel - StreamCaching is not in use. If using streams then its recommended to enable stream caching. See more details at http://camel.apache.org/stream-caching.html
03-12-2020 12:56:08.135 [main] INFO  o.a.c.component.kafka.KafkaConsumer.doStart - Starting Kafka consumer on topic: testtopic9 with breakOnFirstError: false
03-12-2020 12:56:08.145 [main] INFO  o.a.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext.doStartOrResumeRouteConsumers - Route: route1 started and consuming from: kafka://testtopic9?brokers=<domain-name>%3A9092&groupId=test&keyDeserializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.IntegerDeserializer&saslJaasConfig=xxxxxx&saslMechanism=PLAIN&securityProtocol=SASL_SSL&sslKeyPassword=xxxxxx&sslKeystorePassword=xxxxxx&sslTruststoreLocation=C%3A%5CUsers%5CSRJANA%5CDesktop%5CKafka%5Ckafka.client.truststore.jks&valueDeserializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
03-12-2020 12:56:08.148 [main] INFO  o.a.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext.start - Total 1 routes, of which 1 are started
03-12-2020 12:56:08.149 [main] INFO  o.a.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext.start - Apache Camel 2.25.2 (CamelContext: camel-1) started in 0.198 seconds
03-12-2020 12:56:08.151 [main] INFO  c.c.cdc.CDCPostProcessorApplication.logStarted - Started CDCPostProcessorApplication in 3.409 seconds (JVM running for 4.561)
03-12-2020 12:56:08.160 [Camel (camel-1) thread #1 - KafkaConsumer[testtopic9]] INFO  o.a.k.c.consumer.ConsumerConfig.logAll - ConsumerConfig values: 
allow.auto.create.topics = true
    auto.commit.interval.ms = 5000
    auto.offset.reset = latest
    bootstrap.servers = [ <domain-name> ]
    check.crcs = true
    client.dns.lookup = default
    client.id = 
    client.rack = 
    connections.max.idle.ms = 540000
    default.api.timeout.ms = 60000
    enable.auto.commit = true
    exclude.internal.topics = true
    fetch.max.bytes = 52428800
    fetch.max.wait.ms = 500
    fetch.min.bytes = 1
    group.id = e0a4fadb-5e12-49ab-87d5-3b124d3e1c76
    group.instance.id = null
    heartbeat.interval.ms = 3000
    interceptor.classes = []
    internal.leave.group.on.close = true
    isolation.level = read_uncommitted
    key.deserializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
    max.partition.fetch.bytes = 1048576
    max.poll.interval.ms = 300000
    max.poll.records = 500
    metadata.max.age.ms = 300000
    metric.reporters = []
    metrics.num.samples = 2
    metrics.recording.level = INFO
    metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
    partition.assignment.strategy = [org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.RangeAssignor]
    receive.buffer.bytes = 65536
    reconnect.backoff.max.ms = 50
    reconnect.backoff.ms = 50
    request.timeout.ms = 40000
    retry.backoff.ms = 100
    sasl.client.callback.handler.class = null
    sasl.jaas.config = null
    sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd = /usr/bin/kinit
    sasl.kerberos.min.time.before.relogin = 60000
    sasl.kerberos.service.name = null
    sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.jitter = 0.05
    sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.window.factor = 0.8
    sasl.login.callback.handler.class = null
    sasl.login.class = null
    sasl.login.refresh.buffer.seconds = 300
    sasl.login.refresh.min.period.seconds = 60
    sasl.login.refresh.window.factor = 0.8
    sasl.login.refresh.window.jitter = 0.05
    sasl.mechanism = GSSAPI
    security.protocol = PLAINTEXT
    security.providers = null
    send.buffer.bytes = 131072
    session.timeout.ms = 10000
    ssl.cipher.suites = null
    ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2, TLSv1.1, TLSv1]
    ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = https
    ssl.key.password = null
    ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509
    ssl.keystore.location = null
    ssl.keystore.password = null
    ssl.keystore.type = JKS
    ssl.protocol = TLS
    ssl.provider = null
    ssl.secure.random.implementation = null
    ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
    ssl.truststore.location = null
    ssl.truststore.password = null
    ssl.truststore.type = JKS
    value.deserializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer

</pre>
```

Comment: maybe increase the log verbosity and see if it add some details about what's gogin on

Comment: @LucaBurgazzoli , could you please suggest how to do it?

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure you've got a problem here? If the SSL connection to the broker would not work, I would expect the route to fail. But the **route is started**.

You got `auto.offset.reset = latest` in your consumer settings. That means that the consumer **ignores all existing messages** when it connects for the first time.

Have you sent a message to the topic **after** the consumer was started and connected?

Comment: thanks for the reply, yes after I connected to the topic and pushed some records to it

Comment: Sorry, I don't fully understand your comment. was my answer correct or is the problem something else?

Comment: i'm pushing the records but even though it's not working

Comment: I got the solution with camel community, I used different versions for components instead of the same version